# Display log info (progress) on windows form, from separate task classes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'll try to explain my situation as good as I can here.
I have an interface ITask and mutiple tasks implementing that interface. For example let's say there is only one method - Run().
Then I create a List and add the instance of every task to that list. After that I loop through that list and call the Run method of every instance. I don't have the code right here, so I try to create a simple example from memory. Everything to this point works fine, so if there are errors in the code, it's because my bad memory or typos. Don't waste your time to fix that or point that out :)

So the example code that works and explains the situation:

```
    //Interface
    public interface ITask
    {
        void Run();
    }

    //Implementation classes 1..n
    public class Task1 : ITask
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            //do some (long) work
        }
    }

    public class Task2 : ITask ....
    public class TaskN : ITask ....

    //Class to run the tasks
    public class TaskManager()
    {
        public void RunTasks()
        {
            List<ITask> taskList = getTasks();

            foreach (var singleTask in taskList)
            {
                singleTask.Run();
            }
        }

        private List<ITask> getTasks()
        {
            return new List<ITask> {new Task1, new Task2,...,new TaskN};
        }
    }
```

Now what I need to add here is some global log progress that displays info from every task. **One important thing here is that I can only modify (or add new ones) task implementations.** I would like that info to be displayed on ListView for example. So I create a winform and add a listview on that. I also implement a method on that form, let's call that AddInfoToList(string info).

Now maybe my approach itself is complitely wrong here, but what I need help here is that, let's say I create that form in first task

```
    public class Task1 : ITask
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            var progressForm = new ProgressForm();
            progressForm.Show();
        }
    }
```

**The question:**
Form is displayed but
1. As every task is new object, I need somehow to get the instance of that form 
   previously created
2. The form can not be freezed (blank white) and must update the log as the lines are added.
In code something:

```
    public class Task2 : ITask
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            var progressForm = GetTheFormCreatedBySomePreviousTask();

            progressForm.AddInfoToList("Task 2 start something");
            //Do something..
            progressForm.AddInfoToList("Task 2 finished something");
            progressForm.AddInfoToList("Task 2 start something else");
            //Do something else ..
        }
    }
```

I'm greatful for any ideas.
Thank you.

Comment: Your `Task` classes should not be dependent to `Form`. They should just raise some events reporting the progress. Then you can subscribe for those events wherever you need, including a progress form.

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei. I don't know how I didn't come to that by myself. A long day (nice way to excuse I'm stupid) maybe. The  events did the trick and I got it work.